# Serial Hexa dialog (python code to C++/Qt 5.0)

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qextserialport, qtserialport

I need to dialog with a fingerprint on the RS232 port (serial).  I have a python code that works like a charm:

```
import serial
import time

ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyUSB0', 9600, parity='N', timeout=2)
print ser
ser.open()

ser.write(chr(0x00)) # channel 1 byte (alway the same)
ser.write(chr(0x05)) # command 1 byte

ser.write(chr(0x00)) # param1 2 bytes (byte low)
ser.write(chr(0x00)) # param1 2 bytes (byte hight)

ser.write(chr(0x00)) # param2 2 bytes (byte low)
ser.write(chr(0x00)) # param2 2 bytes (byte hight)

ser.write(chr(0x00)) # lwExtraData 2 bytes (byte low)
ser.write(chr(0x00)) # lwExtraData 2 bytes (byte hight)

ser.write(chr(0x00)) # hwExtraData 2 bytes (byte low)
ser.write(chr(0x00)) # hwExtraData 2 bytes (byte hight)

ser.write(chr(0x00)) # ErrorCode 1 byte

sum = 0x05 % 256

ser.write(chr(sum)) # Checksum (modulo 256) 1 byte

print "\nRespuesta Secugen :\n"

cadena = ser.read(12)

for i in range(12):
    print(hex(ord(cadena[i]))),


ser.close()
```

but I need to transform this code for C++/Qt. I don't understand exactly what function I need to use.

I have tried this:

```
serial = new QextSerialPort(serialPort);

    serial->setBaudRate(BAUD9600);
    serial->setFlowControl(FLOW_OFF);
    serial->setParity(PAR_NONE);
    serial->setDataBits(DATA_8);
    serial->setStopBits(STOP_1);
    serial->setTimeout(2);

res = serial->open(QIODevice::ReadWrite);

    if(res)
    {

        QByteArray zero = QByteArray::fromHex("\x00");

       serial->write(zero);

        [...]

      qDebug() << "byte a lire : " << serial->bytesAvailable();
      QByteArray test = serial->readAll();
    }
```

I would like to use the QextSerialPort extension if possible.  I have tried
but without success.  I think I don't understand exactly what conversion I need to do.

-- EDIT --

my question is not really about the class to manage the serial port, sorry my question not was very clear. i don't known what is the solution to reproduce the same code like the python one : send a character to hexa in a RS232.

Comment: What is RS323? Also, do not use QextSerialPort. It is getting updates, but very slowly, and only minor. I would suggest using qtserialport we wrote.

Comment: thank for your help, but my question is more about the conversion between an hexa and a character for reproduce the dialog in the python script.

Comment: error : it's not RS323 but RS232 :)

Comment: Thanks for fixing it. I still recommend QtSerialPort for you though. There is little to no point in using QextSerialPort imo. :-)

Answer (score 1):

QextSerialPort a long time ago there were no updates.
I use [QSerialPort](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.1/qtserialport/qserialport.html).

**Serial.h**

```
class Serial : public QSerialPort{
void openPort(const QString &, const int &, const DataBits &, const  Parity &, const StopBits &, const FlowControl &);

}
```

**Serial.cpp**

```
void Serial::openPort(const QString &serialPort, const int &baudRate, const DataBits &dataBits, const Parity &parity, const StopBits &stopBits, const FlowControl &flowControl) {

            this->serialPort = serialPort;
            this->baudRate = baudRate;
            this->dataBits = dataBits;
            this->parity = parity;
            this->stopBits = stopBits;
            this->flowControl = flowControl;

            this->setPortName(this->serialPort);

            if (this->open(QIODevice::ReadWrite)) {
            } else {
                qDebug() << "\n Can't open port | " << this->errorString();
            }

             if (
                    this->setBaudRate(this->baudRate)
                    && this->setDataBits(this->dataBits)
                    && this->setParity(this->parity)
                    && this->setStopBits(this->stopBits)
                    && this->setFlowControl(this->flowControl)) {
                qDebug() << "\n[ info ]        Port settings successfully";
            } else {
                qDebug() << "\n[ error ]        Port settings failed";
            }
}
```

---

You can use the class Serial in other classes:

```
Serial *serialPort = new Serial();

 if (serialPort->write(data)) {
                qDebug() << "\n[ info ]        data: " << data.toHex() << "         | wrote";
            } else {
                qDebug() << "\n[ error ]        error write data";
            };
```

Answer (score 1):

finaly work with this code :

```
QSerialPort serial;
serial.setPortName(serialPort);

qDebug() << "port : " + serialPort;

if (!serial.open(QIODevice::ReadWrite)) {
    qDebug() << "error open : ";
}

serial.setParity(QSerialPort::NoParity);
serial.setBaudRate(QSerialPort::Baud9600);
serial.setDataBits(QSerialPort::Data8);
serial.setFlowControl(QSerialPort::NoFlowControl);

QByteArray text2 = QByteArray::fromHex("5");
QByteArray text1 = QByteArray::fromHex("0");

serial.write(text1.constData(),1);
serial.write(text2.constData(),1);
serial.write(text1.constData(),1);
serial.write(text1.constData(),1);
serial.write(text1.constData(),1);
serial.write(text1.constData(),1);
serial.write(text1.constData(),1);
serial.write(text1.constData(),1);
serial.write(text1.constData(),1);
serial.write(text1.constData(),1);
serial.write(text1.constData(),1);
serial.write(text2.constData(),1);

if (serial.waitForBytesWritten(1000)) {

    if(serial.waitForReadyRead(1000))
    {
        QByteArray requestData = serial.readAll();
        qDebug() << "byte readed : " <<  requestData.size();

        qDebug() << QString::number(requestData[0], 16);
        qDebug() << QString::number(requestData[1], 16);
        qDebug() << QString::number(requestData[2], 16);
        qDebug() << QString::number(requestData[3], 16);
        qDebug() << QString::number(requestData[4], 16);
        qDebug() << QString::number(requestData[5], 16);
    }
}

serial.close();
```

Comment: Hmm, it is kinda strange code without proper error checking, but I am happy if it works for you today.

Comment: Yes, you are right my code is very ugly (no error check, blocking, etc) ... but it's just for test and yes work for me, so, thank you for your help and your awesome lib :)

Comment: Great, so does it also work with python? There was some python note in your original question.

Comment: yes, the code in this answer is the exact mimic of the python script, both work like expected